# solving singular linear system $Ax=0$

Tags: numerical-methods

what are computational methods for solving square singular linear system $Ax=0$ for a nonzero $x$ with $A$ of large dimensions?

Comment: Due to roundoff error or noise when constructing $A$, we might find that $A$ numerically has full rank.  One approach is to compute the SVD $A = U \Sigma V^T$ and take the singular vector $v_n$, corresponding to the smallest singular value $\sigma_n$, as your null vector.

Comment: Is $A$ sparse? $\,$

Comment: @A is not sparse, but it's symmetric positive definite

Comment: If the coefficients are floating point then it doesn't make sense for the matrix to be singular, if the coefficients are exact then use some sped-up cousin of Gaussian elimination.